# Lost Password Email - default sender?

Tags: php, email, default, send

I am working on a script, however my default email sender is 2297337@host.myhost.com

How do I configure it using PHP to a custom email such as admin@mydomain.com

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: ... are you using PHP's `mail()` function?

Comment: Use a custom `header`, like "From: admin@mydomain.com"

Comment: Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and your life will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://phpmailer.worxware.com/.  Works easier.
Or else you could use some mail headers:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Good luck!